# Why does my shell not work properly on RHEL-family systems I SSH into?

Tags: bash, ssh, fedora

I have continually had problems with shell behavior when SSHing into RHEL-family hosts such as Fedora, CentOS, or actual RHEL. I only seem to have these problems when SSHing into this family of Linux distributions, and I confess it's such a frustration I'm about to stop using them altogether where I make the choice.

The bad behavior is an apparent failure to recognize the beginning of the terminal line and it makes it very difficult to modify previously used commands as well as other issues.

Some diagnostic things I have checked in the past including confirming that $TERM matches on SSH client and host. In the demo below both use the same:

```
nborgers@Persons-Laptop ~ % echo $TERM
xterm-256color
nborgers@Persons-Laptop util % ssh gateway -t 'bash -ic "echo $TERM"' 
xterm-256color
Connection to 10.212.100.192 closed.
```

In this demo my client is MacOS but I have the same issues when SSHing from WSL, so a Linux VM.

[image: Demo of shell working properly on MacOS zsh and then not working properly when I SSH into a Fedora instance]

**[Applying accepted solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/765733/101598)**:
This is what I was doing wrong as a diff to my Ansible playbook:

```
nborgers@Persons-Laptop host-config-as-code % git diff --ignore-space-at-eol
diff --git a/ssh/terminal_colors.yaml b/ssh/terminal_colors.yaml
index 6751809..33bb779 100644
--- a/ssh/terminal_colors.yaml
+++ b/ssh/terminal_colors.yaml
@@ -12,6 +12,6 @@
     lineinfile:
       path: /etc/bashrc
       state: present
-      line: 'export PS1="\e[0;{{ color }}m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "'
+      line: 'export PS1="\[\033[01;{{ color }}m\]\u@\h \[\033[0m\]\W $ "'
     when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```

I've apparently been inflicting this on myself with some colorization configuration. I still feel like I've seen this on machines I hadn't done this to, but I can't recreate the problem anymore.

Comment: Indeed @steeldriver, thank you. Updated command and included output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual reason for the behavior in your demo is that your prompt string contains terminal control strings that have not been properly specified as non-printing characters (e.g. enclosed within `\[`...`\]` in `bash`, or within `%{`...`%}` in `zsh`, and similar methods in other shells).

Unlike `bash`, `zsh` already has built-in prompt color escape codes that will automatically be counted as non-printing, so you might not have been aware that such enclosures are needed in other shells.

As a result, the shell will miscalculate how many visible character cells are taken up by the prompt string, leading to confusion about when the cursor should wrap to the next line, or back to the previous line when moving backwards on a wrapped command line.

You should review your `$PS1` or `$PROMPT` definitions, and make sure any non-printing character sequences not directly documented on the respective shell's man page are enclosed in the appropriate shell-dependent way.